# Hashing in Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large matrix that I'm planning to store as a list of dictionaries in Python. The matrix is mostly 0's and I was wondering if the hashing function in the dictionary would store leading space for each row. So, for instance if I initialise a 100,000 x 100,000 matrix but only about 1,000 entries in each row store actual elements and for row 50,000 I have entries from 48,500 to 50,500 would Python create a dictionary of size 50,500 or 2,000? Further, if the former is true is there a way I could optimise within Python's current dictionary class or would I need to create my own?

As an example of my code, I have this:

```
class DictArray:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.Width = width
        self.Height = height
        self.Data = [0 for _ in range(self.Height) ]

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if (self.Data[ k[0] ] == 0):
            return 0
        elif (k[1] in self.Data[ k[0] ]):
            return self.Data[ k[0] ][ k[1] ]
        else:
            return 0

    def __setitem__(self, k, value):
        if (self.Data[ k[0] ] == 0):
            self.Data[ k[0] ] = { k[1] : value }
        else:
            self.Data[ k[0] ][ k[1] ] = value
```

Comment: Show us how you're initializing the 100,000 x 100,000 matrix.

Comment: Show a sample for a smaller matrix and the dictionary that will hold it

Comment: SciPy and NumPy are likely the libraries you need if you want to efficiently handle sparse matrix processing.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a job for `scipy.sparse`. SciPy's sparse matrix implementations will do a lot better than what you're putting together.

Comment: Your `self.Data` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you'll look at `__setitem__`, you'll notice it's actually a list of dictionaries. This isn't how I plan on doing this; it's just one way you could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary will be sized based on the number of keys you store in it.

If you have 2000 keys (each a `(x, y)` coordinate, perhaps?) then it'll be sized to hold 2000 keys (plus a little overhead to facilitate future growth without needing to resize).

However, if you are going to create keys for all 10^10 elements in your matrix (with all but 2000 referencing `None`, say), then you'll have a dictionary with 10 billion keys and it'll be sized accordingly.

Using a dictionary to build a sparse matrix can be as easy as:

```
class DictArray:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self._data = {}

    def _validate_coords(self, x, y):
        if not (0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height):
            raise IndexError((x, y))

    def __getitem__(self, x_y):
        self._validate_coords(*x_y)
        return self._data.get(x_y, 0)

    def __setitem__(self, x_y, value):
        self._validate_coords(*x_y)
        if value == 0:
            try:
                del self._data[x_y]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        else:
            self._data[x_y] = value
```

Demo:

```
>>> da = DictArray(10, 10)
>>> da[0, 0] = 42
>>> da[0, 4] = 81
>>> len(da._data)
2
>>> da[0, 4] = 0
>>> len(da._data)
1
>>> da._data
{(0, 0): 42}
>>> da[0, 0]
42
>>> da[0, 4]
0
```

I'd urge you to look at SciPy or NumPy for such a large task, however. They have dedicated data structures for such tasks, such as those found in the [`scipy.sparse` module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: I like your suggestion. I would use NumPy or SciPy for this but this project is destined for translation later so I want to depend on as few external libraries as possible

Comment: @Woody1193: Whatever language you translate it to, you should probably get a sparse matrix library for that language too, or at least read up on standard sparse matrix formats and algorithms. The standard approaches are going to perform a lot better than what you first come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sparse matrix, you might try to get away with the dictionary where the key is a (row,col) tuple (or some other way to quickly get row and column).

E.g.

```
# assume get_matrix(i,j) gives your (i,j)th element
m = {}
for i in xrange(0,100000):
    for j in xrange(0,100000):
        t = get_matrix(i,j)
        if t:
            m[(i,j)] = t
```

Regarding dictionary performance, assuming it has logarithmic search complexity, you might also look at how much memory it's going to take. Depending on what kind of machine you are using, something like 10K entries might work, but something like 1000K entries might not.

(but using numpy or scipy might be a better option)